# Runtime error while implementing vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to implement my own version of vector in c++. 
So far I have done this..

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


template<class T>
class vec
{
public:
    T *a;
    int i,N;
    vec(int N=0):N(N)
    {
        i=-1;
        a=(T *)malloc(N*sizeof(T));
    }
    void push_back(const T& t);
    T at(const int& index) const;
};

template<class T>
void vec<T>::push_back(const T& t)
{
    if(++i==N)
    {
        a=(T *)realloc(a,(++N)*sizeof(T));
    }
    a[i]=t;
}

template<class T>
T vec<T>::at(const int& index) const
{
    return a[index];
}

int main()
{
    vec<string> v;
    v.push_back("2");
    v.push_back("1");
    v.push_back("3");
    cout<<v.at(0)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting a run time error when I run this
Where is the error in the above code?
I am using c++ and visual studio to run.

Comment: delete and malloc do not go together; you want free or new

Comment: The `malloc` (and `realloc`) functions only *allocate* memory. They do not call constructors. Using `malloc` to allocate memory for objects with constructors will not work very well, unless you manually go through all objects and explicitly construct them.

Comment: So how do I handle this ?

Comment: To add on from Some programmer, you can do this with "placement new" or just new[]  I strongly suggest the latter, and the removal of your malloc / realloc

Comment: but I cannot increase the memory using new if I need to push many elements..

Comment: @Percy123 look up new[]  in your c++ book, and then look up assignment operators (or copy constructors, either will do for this case).

Comment: @Percy123 It's certainly a bad idea to have `using namespace std;` in a header file, and name a class `vector`.

Comment: corrected that ..

Comment: In general it would also be helpful to add error messages and where the error occurs.

Comment: @Percy123 Having the `using namespace std;` in a header file is still a bad idea, even if you change the name of your class.

Comment: Why is it a header file?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use placement new.

something like this:

```
// Allocate memory
void* mem = malloc(sizeof(std::string));

// Call constructor via placement new on already allocated memory
std::string* ptr = new (mem) std::string();
```

But then, you are forced to explicitly call destructor for this memory

```
ptr->~std::string();
```

Overall - this is not really good way to achieve what you want. It's more convenient to use usual new\delete operators and copy internal data on re-allocation (how it was done in STL vector)

Comment: Which part of code are you pointing at? .. can you edit the provided code instead

Comment: @Percy123 in push_back you allocate memory via malloc, call placement new, and then assign.